# Trouble on rendering a template passing a local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to render a template (`show.html.erb`) passing a local variable.

In `RAILS_ROOT/views/users/show.html.erb` I have

```
Name: <%= @user.name %>
Surname: <%= @user.surname %>
```

I have also a page controller to handle pages and in the `application_controller.rb` an istance of `@current_user`. A page is called `user`, so in `RAILS_ROOT/views/pages/user.html.erb` I have

```
<%= render :template => "users/show", :locals => { :user => @current_user } %>
```

The above code doesn't work (I get this error: `RuntimeError in Pages#user, Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`) but this works:

```
<%= render :template => "users/show", :locals => { :user => @user = @current_user } %>
```

*I think it is not a good approach* to "overwrite" the `@user` variable. This is because, for example, if I need to recall `@user` after the above 'render' statement it will don't work anymore.

**So, what is a solution in order to render `show.html.erb`?**

---

I tryed also

```
<%= render :template => "users/show", :locals => { @user => @current_user } %>
<%= render :template => "users/show", :locals => { :object => @current_user, :as => @user }
```

but those don't work.

---

**UPDATE**

If in `pages_controller.rb` I put this

```
def user
  @user ||= @current_user
end
```

it will work and in the view files you can just use

```
<%= render :template => "users/show" %>
```

Anyway, I discoverd that I have this error (see below for more info):

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Pages#user
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

The error is generated from this *form* statement located in a partial loaded from `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => user_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
:locals => { :user => @current_user }
```

and in template

```
Name: <%= user.name %>
```

Local variables are local, so you don't need `@` to refer them.

**@user502052**
You can render view explicitly from your controller.

```
render :template => "users/show", :locals => {...}
```

When you don't execute `render` in controller, framework does that for you with default parameters. When you do, you can specify different template file, pass local variables, render a partial: anything `render` function supports.

Comment: Ok, your code works. But, since in my view I have the statement `@user` (other controllers depend on the statement `@user`), I need to use that "format".

Comment: @user502052 `@user` is a global variable, you can't 'localize' it. I would suggest passing local variables from your controller in the same way.

Comment: In order to using `@user` instead of `user` in my views, what I have to change in `users_controller.rb` if I have, for example, `def show @user = User.find(params[:id]) ... end`?

Comment: @user502052 I've added some information about it to the post.

Comment: I updated the question with a solution. What do you think about?

Comment: @user502052 If global variables work for you, I don't see why not. It's a lot about personal preference.

Comment: Thankssss ! Worked like a charm!! in controller: return render :template => "contests/instagram", :locals => { :photos => @photos, :videos => @videos}

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you are NOT rendering a partial, and do not want to use :template option, this can also be done in Rails 4 with:

```
render 'users/show', {user: @current_user}
```

Answer (score 0):

Url:

```
http://localhost/pages/user
```

this will call the user method on pages_controller. You have this:

```
def user
  @user ||= @current_user
end
```

Rails creates an instance variable @users and by default will try to render a view template at app/views/pages/user.html.erb. If that is not what you want, you have to say so in the controller:

```
def user
  @user ||= @current_user
  render :template => "users/show", :locals => { :user => @current_user }
end
```

This will now render app/views/users/show.html.erb with a local variable called user instead of the default app/views/pages/user.html.erb.

Currently you are waiting until you are inside a view template and then asking to render another view template. Once you are in a view template you should only need to render partial templates:

```
render :partial => 'users/show', :locals => {:user => @current_user}
```

Hopefully that helps clarify.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem. All rendering work, except the one explained in the UPDATE of this question... damn ':url => user_path'!!!. I also opened a specific question for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021966/trouble-with-the-url-statement-of-a-form-using-nested-partials-and-templates. thanks again.

Comment: What do you have in your routes.rb?