# Passing from using '@user' to using 'user' in 'html.erb' files: how and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, view

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and [I was advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020553/trouble-on-rendering-a-template-passing-a-local-variable) (`@user is a global variable, you can't 'localize' it. I would suggest passing local variables from your controller in the same way.`) to use variables like `user` instead of `@user` in view files. **Why to do that, exactly?**.

So, I am considering pass from using `@user` to using `user`. That is, (in `html.erb` file) from using

```
@user.name
```

to using

```
user.name
```

At this time, for example, in the show method of my controller I have:

```
def show
  @user = Users.find(1)
  ...
end
```

**What I have to change in the controller to do that works in views?**

Comment: that's non sense, only instance_variables are sent from the controller to the view.

Comment: Nikita Rybak (http://stackoverflow.com/users/330565/nikita-rybak) was wrong in his answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020553/trouble-on-rendering-a-template-passing-a-local-variable)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only something you need to worry about when the same partial is called in the views from more than one controller.

Having a partial that is using @user in it (likely set in a users_controller), means that the moment you call that partial in a view from some other controller (for example; accounts_controller) that does not set @users you will get an error. If you reference only local variables in your partial you can set them as needed from any controller with the :locals hash that was described.

Comment: What you say is true, but there is a way to solve this problem\error?

Comment: Are you sharing a partial in the views from two separate controllers? If not, there is no reason to change anything. If you are let me know and I'll post some code :)

Comment: Yes. An example (with some specific) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020553/trouble-on-rendering-a-template-passing-a-local-variable (see the UPDATE). If you need some other information, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

That's non sense, only instance_variables are sent from the controller to the view.

Nikita Rybak was not wrong in his answer, he just passed the instance variable contained in his view (`@current_user`) to a partial where it has a different name (`user`):

```
 :locals => { :user => @current_user }
```

he concluded very well:

> Local variables are local, so you don't need @ to refer them.

Indeed you have two choices when working with a partial:

- assume it has access to the instance variable (which is not advised)
- pass the instance variable to the partial with a local name which is the Rails' way

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Rails Best Practice](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable). Using local variables is preferable way when rendering partials (those view files which start with a `_`). That's because you'll need review your controller's code to know about instance variable.